# Moscow ML in Aquamacs

Tags: macos, sml, aquamacs

Does any of you mac-users know how to get Moscow ML (mosml) to work in aquamacs? I have installed mosml through macports and it is working in the terminal. I have also installed Sml-mode in Aquamacs but cant get it to compile my active SML file. Anyone who know a guide ? or an alternative editor for this to work?

Thanks,.

Comment: Any chance of posting errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not an error actually... It was just me who was a little stupid for a moment :) .. Turns out when trying to compile a sml file en aquamacs with the emacs command it had a wrong cd path for the mosml compiler. I changed it to the correct one and now it works